# Can you not to export an instance in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Yeah, I know this sounds unreasonable. Guess there are better approaches than simply hiding an instance.

I'm working on a library about images. Inside one module, there is an enum type for the sizes of the images:

```hs
module Sizes (Sizes(..)) where

data Size = Original
          | Regular
          | Small
          | Thumb
          | Mini
```

Now I need to parse sizes from strings, particularly in a case-insensitive way (e.g. `"original"`, `"Original"`, `"ORIGINAL"` should all be parsed to `Original`). I planned the following:

1. Derive the `Read` instance for `Size`
2. Create another function `readSize` to parse from string, making use of `read` and `readMaybe`
3. Hide the `Read` instantiation from users so they do not mistakenly use `read` or whatsoever when, say, parsing `"ORIGINAL"`

Dirty enough. Anyway, here are the first two steps, and I have no idea how to conduct step 3.

```hs
data Size = ...
          deriving (Read)

readSize :: String -> Maybe Size
readSize s
  | (toLower <$> s) `elem` ["original", "regular", "small", "thumb", "mini"] = (read . onlyCapitaliseFirst) s
  | otherwise = readMaybe s
  where onlyCapitaliseFirst ""     = ""
        onlyCapitaliseFirst (c:xs) = toUpper c : (toLower <$> xs)
```

Why don't I just write the instance myself, you may ask?
Well, because it's too inelegant and tiresome to implement such `readsPrec`,
which would be much better if the compiler just use some magic to complete it for me.

```hs
instance Read Size where
  readsPrec _ = \case ('o' : 'r' : 'i' : 'g' : 'i' : 'n' : 'a' : 'l' : xs) -> [(Original, XS)]
                      ...  -- it's not even correct, for only considering all lowercase case
```

Comment: No you cannot hide an instance. BUT Haskell's parser libraries are best-in-class, so the good news is it's really easy to write the thing you want without making an instance in the first place!

Comment: You would typically write a free standing parser function instead of using `Read` for cases like this, in no small part because of issues like this (in the first place, `Read` isn't used _that_ much IRL because you'd typically choose some format other than haskell terms for serialisation anyhow).

Comment: Notice that compiler generated code for `Read` and `Show` instances is mutually compatible. Meaning, that they are sort of inverses: `x == read (show x)` (same apply to `s == show (read s)` up to whitespaces). Hence, a good/common practice is to follow this "inversion" rule. Hence, It is better to not make an instance of `Read` typeclass by your own. So, define your own parsing function and don't bother to much about implementing `Read` typeclass, and if you do implement it, use the compiler's implementation better.

Comment: Your `readSize` function doesn't look **very** much less complicated than it would be to write a parse function from scratch (with good libraries); with the `elem` check you've already basically decided it's the string you're looking for before you pass it to `read`! Your example `Read Size` showing why you don't want to write it manually is a strawman; no idiomatic Haskell would match a case-insensitive string by manually writing out character literals and list constructors! But a "proper" function suiting your need shouldn't be a `Read` instance anyway, since it's not reading Haskell syntax.

Comment: Writing `Read` instances to parse something other than Haskell syntax is like writing `FromJSON` instances to parse something other than JSON. Sure you *might* be able to make it work, but why? The machinery simply isn't *for* that; there are easier and better ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I prefer to do this way:

1. Deriving Enum and Show (not Read) instances

   ```
   data Size = Original | ...
       deriving (Enum, Show)
   ```
2. Make parse function

   ```
   readSize :: String -> Maybe Size
   readSize str = lookup (toLower <$> str) size_map
     where
       size_map = [(toLower <$> show size, size) | size <- [Original ..]]
   ```